# How to connect female reversed with female normal TNC

Tags: tnc

I would like to ask how can I connect device, which have female reversed TNC connector with antenna which have female normal TNC. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the applicable reverse-polarized TNC adapter.  Sounds like you have a standard TNC Female on your antenna

[image]

and a RP-TNC Female on your device.

[image]

Can you confirm?

### ----------

*Added 31-May-2018*

Based on your comments I'm concerned that you are not certain of your determination of the existing connectors.  (It's easy to confuse standard TNCs with RP-TNCs and males with females etc.)

If those pictured above are truly what you have then the following pair of adapters would work:

---

This TNC-Male to N-Female adapts the antenna connector to N-female

[L-com Item # AXA-NFTM](http://www.l-com.com/coaxial-coaxial-adapter-n-female-tnc-male)

[image: L-com Item # AXA-NFTM]

---

This N-Male to RP-TNC-Male adapts the first adapter to the device connector:

[L-com Item # AXA-NMRTP](http://www.l-com.com/coaxial-coaxial-adapter-n-male-rp-tnc-plug)
[image: L-com Item # AXA-NMRTP]

Comment: Yes, I have these connectors which are on the images. Do I need something like this https://www.data-alliance.net/adapter-rp-tnc-female-to-female-gender-changer-cable-coupler/ ?

Comment: Something "like" that,  but not that. That looks like a straight male-to-male . You need a RP-TNC on one end and a standard TNC on the other.    I've looked and have not found a single adapter.  You may need two adapters

Comment: Could you tell me which ones?

Comment: Or what about this https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/coaxial-adapter-rp-tnc-female-to-n-female/

Comment: No,  the OP has females.  Needs males. Also,  that connector has as N on one end.

Comment: @aladar90 : I updated / edited my answer.  It might be helpful to post pics of the two connectors you have so we can verify their identification.